# Why would a Web API entity collection GET work but the single entity GET return 404.0?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, odata, iis-express, asp.net-web-api-routing

We have an OData 4 WebAPI controller with two GET methods, one that returns a `Thing` entity collection (`IQueryable<Thing>`) and one that returns a single `Thing` (`SingleResult<Thing>`) based on the provided key (using the `FromODataUri` attribute).

When run, IIS and IISExpress happily return an entity collection when you request `http://localhost:48213/odata/Things`, but return a `404.0 - Not Found` when we request a single entity on `http://localhost:48213/odata/Things(1)` (the notification coming from `MapRequestHandler` and the Handler being `StaticFile`).  The GET method for the single entity is not executed.

The project was created following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) and I think we've followed it correctly.  This feels like a URL mapping issue (perhaps `web.config` or IIS/IISExpress config related), because the URL is extension-less and contains parentheses.  However, I guess it could be the route configuration or some other thing I don't get.  Does anybody have any ideas?

The `Thing` type declaration is as follows (in F#):

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Thing =
    { Id   : string
      Name : string }
```

Comment: Can you post the source code for the definition for the 'Thing' entity?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @GlennFerrie. I've added the `Thing` type.

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be `http://localhost:48213/odata/Things/1`?

Comment: @Mrchief AFAIK the OData URL convention for addressing a single entity by it's key is `/entity(key)`.  See the [OData URL Conventions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html) for details (if you need to get to sleep!).  *BTW - I did try your suggestion, but get the same 404.0 result.*

Comment: Just making sure... :) Thanks for the URL!

Comment: Could you also post the controller methods you wrote for getting the single `Thing`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the type of the key parameter in your controller ? If it is string, you should have the url:

```
/odata/Things('1')
```

Comment: `/odata/Things('1')` does not work either, as the controller `key` is of type `int`.  However, this type discrepancy is probably the cause of the routing issue.  Thanks for the suggestion and I'll dig further.

Comment: OK, the issue was due to the type discrepancy and the usage of `MapODataServiceRoute` with an `IEdmModel` built using the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.  I'd like to document this well for future muppets like me.  If you get what I'm saying, do you want to update your answer (as you led me to this) or do you want me to answer it fully and accept my own?

Comment: I think you should post your own, you can describe better the situation.

Comment: The type of ID in model and your controller should be the same, either string or int